# textmodel wordfish in quanteda

Tags: quanteda

I' am trying to understand the logic of ideological scaling. I have a dataset consisting of monetary and fiscal policy related texts with a dimension t (=time), and j (institution). I would like to scale the texts using wordfish.

example of quanteda package:

---

```
irish_dfm <- dfm(data_corpus_irishbudget2010, remove_punct = TRUE)
wf <- textmodel_wordfish(irish_dfm, dir = c(6,5))
summary(wf)
```

---

The dir = c(6,5) setting is not clear to me.

At https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/quanteda/versions/1.3.4/topics/textmodel_wordfish

it is stated that

> "set global identification by specifying the indexes for a pair of
>   documents such that ^θdir[1]<^θdir[2]."

Does it mean I have to pick two documents and read and impose that theta of doc 1 is lower that theta of doc 2?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what it means.